# c# find mouse position relative to form element

Tags: c#, position, mouse

I am trying to deal with a mouse event that reacts according to mouse position relative to the element that receives the event. The thing is, event handlers normally receive parameters like this:

(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) // as generated by IDE

and I can retrieve the mouse position with the values e.X and e.Y. Those are the values of the mouse pointer relative to the whole window.

Each element in the form has some properties like Location.X and Location.Y, which represent the position of the upper left corner relative to its container. The thing is, unless the element is not inside another container inside the window, finding the position relative to the element with something like

e.X - thing.Location.X,  e.Y - thing.Location.Y

will not work. Furthermore, I will have to keep track of where is the element located, if I place it inside a panel with subdivisions I have to keep track of the location of each subdivision above it, etc.

How do I get the relative position of the mouse to an element in the window, without keeping track of containers, or having to edit the code each time I move the element from one container to another in edit time? or how do I get the relative position of the element to the whole window once and for all?

tnx

--- edit:

it seems in controls there is a method called GetContainerControl; I could make a loop that adds the location of each parent container till there are no more containers, and I will keep it as an alternative, but I find it kind of clumsy

Comment: are you using WPF, WinForm, GTK#?

Comment: Look into the screen to client and back function! [PointToClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoclient(v=vs.110).aspx) and [PointToScreen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoscreen(v=vs.110).aspx) ! Along with [Control.MousePosition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseposition(v=vs.110).aspx) they will let you do what you want..

Comment: yes, according to a quick read it seems PointToClient is what I was looking for, tnx!